# change ownership recursive folder powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file-ownership

I am looking to change ownership of many thousands of files and folders from one specific user to another.

Within the folder structure most of the files and folders need to have their ownership changed from UserA to UserB, but there are some files owned by UserC that we need to leave untouched.

I had found a previous question which seemed to be asking the same as this, but I can no longer find it to reference. It did give the below though.

```
$FolderToScan = "G:\Folder\Folder\Folder"
$OldOwner = "Domain\User"
$NewOwner = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain","User")

$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $FolderToScan -Recurse

Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $f = Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName
    $f = $f.GetAccessControl('Access')
    If ($f.Owner -eq $OldOwner) {
        $f.SetOwner($NewOwner)
        Set-Acl -path $file.FullName -aclObject $f
    }
}
```

When I run the above with the correct details in place of domain/user, nothing happens.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: I would recommend giving ownership to the administrators group and handle access to the files by adjusting the ACLs.

Answer (score 2):

when I tried the code it always returned nothing for for the owner field.
try these changes in the foreach loop.

this worked for me

```
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.fullname
    $f = Get-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName
    $acl = (get-acl $f)
    $acl.owner
    If ($acl.Owner -eq $OldOwner) {
        $acl.SetOwner($NewOwner)
        Set-Acl -path $file.FullName -aclObject $acl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version can look like this:

```
$NewOwner = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain","User")
$OldOwner = "Domain\User"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force "Path/To/Folder" | Get-Acl | ? { $_.Owner -eq "$OldOwner" } | % { $_.SetOwner($NewOwner); $_ } | Set-Acl
```

If you don't need any filtering, you can just drop the `Where-Object` / `?` block.